# Calling helper functions in a Python `__init__` function

Tags: object-oriented, python, class-design

### Problem

I am currently working with a **class** that necessarily has a **very complicated initialization function** (>350 lines of code) given that many computations and attributes need to be performed and defined.

I am considering using either helper functions within the `__init__` function of this class in order to make the code cleaner and broken into logical components; however, I am not sure the best way to go about this.

For context, the class is a Neural Network (PyTorch) and the `init` function contains several blocks of code that are essentially large if-else trees that define the values of attributes based off of the `init` inputs. It is these blocks that I feel are logically distinct and could therefore be placed into their own functions.

### Potential Solutions:

In particular, I see **4 potential methods**, and I'm hoping that to get clarifications on the **pros, cons, and dangers** of each of these methods.

**I've listed each of the methods out below with some example code - any advice is greatly appreciated!**

#### Method 1

Do not change anything, and keep a very large `__init__` function:

```py
class ClassName(SuperClass):

  def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, ..., argN):
    # <350 lines of code setting attribute values>
```

#### Method 2

**Define default attribute values** at the top of `__init__`, **and then override them** with **instance** functions based on `__init__`'s arguments. The reason for listing the attributes out at the top of `__init__` is so that all attributes are clearly listed out in one location.

The `_fn`s will require access to `self` and potentially some `__init__` arguments.

```py
class ClassName(SuperClass):

  def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, ..., argN):
    super().__init__()

    # Attribute defaults
    self.attr1 = None
    self.attr2 = None
    # ...
    self.attrM = None

    # Set attributes
    self._fn1()
    self._fn2()
    # ...
    self._fnM()

  def _fn1(self, **relevant_args):
    # <relevant computations>
    self.attr1 = #<result-of-relevant-computations>

  def _fn2(self, **relevant_args):
    # <relevant computations>
    self.attr2 = #<result-of-relevant-computations>

  # ...

  def _fnM(self, **relevant_args):
    # <relevant computations>
    self.attrM = #<result-of-relevant-computations>
```

This has the benefit of compartmentalizing the code

#### Method 3 (variation of 2)

The same as Method 2 except **return a value** in the helper functions and then assign those to the instance attributes. Not sure if this makes a difference / is better because it is **more explicit about which attributes are being set where**. Also has the potential to avoid listing default attribute values which would make the code shorter.

The `_fn`s will usually require access to `self` and potentially some `__init__` arguments.

```py
class ClassName(SuperClass):

  def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, ..., argN):
    super().__init__()

    # Attribute defaults (could potentially remove with this approach)
    self.attr1 = None
    self.attr2 = None
    # ...
    self.attrM = None

    # Set attributes
    self.attr1 = self._fn1()
    self.attr2 = self._fn2()
    # ...
    self.attrM = self._fnM()

  def _fn1(self, **relevant_args):
    # <relevant computations>
    return #<result-of-relevant-computations>

  def _fn2(self, **relevant_args):
    # <relevant computations>
    return #<result-of-relevant-computations>

  # ...

  def _fnM(self, **relevant_args):
    # <relevant computations>
    return = #<result-of-relevant-computations>
```

#### Method 4

Define **inner functions** within `__init__` that set all relevant attributes, either as in method 2 or method 3. This has the benefit of not cluttering the instance function list, but makes the `__init__` function messy.

```py
class ClassName(SuperClass):

  def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, ..., argN):
    # Helper functions
    def fn1(self, **relevant_args):
      # <relevant computations>
      return #<result-of-relevant-computations>

    # ...

    def fnM(self, **relevant_args):
      # <relevant computations>
      return = #<result-of-relevant-computations>

    super().__init__()


    # Attribute defaults (could potentially remove with this approach)
    self.attr1 = None
    # ...
    self.attrM = None

    # Set attributes
    self.attr1 = _fn1()
    # ...
    self.attrM = _fnM()
```

Finally, I supposed I could define any pure functions at the module level and pass in attributes as arguments, but I do not really think it makes sense to do this since these functions will not be used anywhere else and are pretty specific to the class itself.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: I'd personally move all of that out of the class - I'd create a data structure that I'd initialize by some free function before creating the class, then I'd pass that data structure into the class via a constructor parameter. The class would not be responsible for initialization, except that it would perform some sanity checks (like that the argument is not `None`), and it would be entirely focused on its specific task.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović thanks for your input! To clarify, you mean have some function `attr_generator` defined at the module level which would take in the arguments that currenty go into `ClassName`'s `__init__` function, perform all necessary computations, and then return an e.g. dictionary of attribute value pairs? And then pass this into the `__init__` function to set the instance attributes?

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72889479/how-to-set-instance-parameters-with-functions-in-init-python "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: Pretty much - except that I wouldn't necessarily use a dictionary. You can create a class that's just meant to be a simple data structure - it just holds the data and does nothing else; has no methods, performs no checks. Contains what you'd previously assign as `self.attribute`-s in your original class. It doesn't have to be a single data class, though. If you have groups of attributes (e.g. input params, output params, network params) - you could create a couple of such data classes to name and represent each group. 1/2

Comment: And I wouldn't use it to set the instance attributes (although you can do that), I'd just use the data structure itself (as in `self.data = parameter`, or alternatively `self.data = copy(parameter)`) - the internals of the class would then access `self.data.attr1`, `self.data.attr2`, etc. I'd try to give it a better name than `data`, though. 2/2

Comment: @gnat - the OP was instructed to post here, and has said in their comment there "I will remove this question in a bit (in case you need to respond)."

Comment: @FilipMilovanović thank you very much for this answer - I definitely see why this makes sense. I'm not sure if I need to set instance attributes to ensure that backprop works as intended (not sure how PyTorch would handle this), but I will start experimenting and implement some verison of this. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yeah, integration with PyTorch would definitively affect the details of how you'd do this, but I don't think it throws a wrench in the works when it comes to the basic idea. I don't know exactly what your class does, but my assumption in the answer was that it has some methods that you've added for your own use (as opposed to, say, because they were required by PyTorch). Note also that, instead of PyTorch operating on your class, you could probably also make it work by passing this internal data structure to PyTorch instead. But yeah, there's bound to be some amount of experimentation.

Comment: maybe have a `__new__` add do static declartion here and then use them in `__init__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide a lot of detail, but this usually happens because you're trying to do too much in one class.

Now, if you don't want to clutter your class with helper functions, you could, as others have suggested on the StackOverflow main site, define your helpers outside of the class.

But, in this case, I'd personally move all of that initialization code out of the class - I'd create a plain data structure that I'd initialize using some free function before creating the class, then I'd pass that data structure into the class via a constructor parameter.

The class would then not be responsible for parameter initialization and the associated decision logic, except that it would perform some sanity checks (like that the argument is not None). It would be entirely focused on the specific task it was designed to do, once the values of the parameters have been decided on by something else.

In your original post on StackOverflow, you expressed your concern that "none of the code would be useful beyond initializing the class", but that's not really an issue. You don't necessarily separate things out because they'd be useful elsewhere, but because doing this lets you make your code cleaner and more readable. It lets you introduce meaningful names and divide work between parts of your codebase.

If what you really have are groups of attributes or parameters - e.g. (and I'm making these up) input params, output params, network params - you could create a number of such plain data classes, each letting you name and represent each group. It doesn't have to be a single data class.

Doing this could potentially simplify your initialization logic, as you'd only need to focus on the subset of values covered by each class. If it becomes simple enough, you could end up distributing it between the `__init__` methods of each of these classes.

Comment: Thanks very much for compiling this into one succinct answer Filip!

Comment: I believe it's also "bad practice" to do too much work inside `__init__` (but still looking for references on that). Probably at the very least, and a model not listed in your options, you can create separate methods for setting the values, and just set all the attributes to None or whatever inside `__init__`. Once the object is created you can then call the appropriate initialisers, and even provide another method that given a minimal set of inputs can decide which initialisers to call.

Comment: @NeilG - yeah, it's a general advice across languages not to do "too much work" inside a constructor (where what exactly constitutes "too much" is a bit blurry). Generally speaking, I don't like the "assign values after construction using setters" idea - you should strive to make it difficult to construct objects in an invalid state, unless it represents something like, say, a plain data structure somewhere at the edge of the application that collects user input and is expected to exist in an invalid state part of the time.

Comment: Thanks @FilipMilovanović, I guess I was trying to find some concrete reasons but some things aren't exact I guess. I think you've nailed it there. The constructor is particularly to ensure you always create a valid object initially. That's probably where the role of the constructor should stop (most of the time).